# How to change text color for Theme?

Tags: flutter

This is my code, I don't understand, how to change text color for theme

```
void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title: 'Характеристика',
    home: new CharacteristList(),
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue,
    accentColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use **textTheme**:

```
theme: new ThemeData(
  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
  textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
     bodyColor: Colors.blue,
     displayColor: Colors.blue,
  ))
```

Comment: which content do you mean?

Comment: this is mistake, 'context'

Comment: I don't get your idea. When adding this code under build(BuildContext context) method, we have context already. Can you share your build method?

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Is this really the only solution? Do we really need to have access to the context to change the text color in a theme. You can change scaffoldbackgroundcolor without this. Why making is this more complex thant needed... :(

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. This solution is for changing the text color for the whole app