# "'textTheme' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.": No named parameter with the name 'textTheme'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running a flutter app template. However, it breaks at lib/main.dart.

```
    AppBarTheme _lightAndroidBar = AppBarTheme(
        centerTitle: true,
        color: Color(COLOR_PRIMARY),
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: 0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
        brightness: Brightness.light);
```

It says
`Error: No named parameter with the name 'textTheme'.`

textTheme is part of the 'material' library, which is imported on line 10:
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

The package doesn't seem to have any dependencies.

I tried wrapping the icontheme and texttheme in an theme: ThemeData() after looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423987/how-to-set-text-color-theme-for-entire-app-in-flutter#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20textTheme%20property%20in%20the%20Material,%28%29%2C%20bodyText2%3A%20TextStyle%20%28%29%2C%29.apply%20%28bodyColor%3A%20Colors.orange%2C%20displayColor%3A%20Colors.blue%2C%29%2C%29%2C%29) to see if that was also undefined, and got a different error with no parameter "theme."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v2.4.0-0.0.pre `textTheme` is deprecated.

The alternative(s) would be to use:

- `toolbarTextStyle`
- `titleTextStyle`

Now, `headline6` in your code is also now deprecated. instead, use `titleLarge`

Your complete refactored code would look like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

AppBarTheme _lightAndroidBar = AppBarTheme(
    centerTitle: true,
    color: Color(0xFFE0E0E0), // <-- Change to COLOR_PRIMARY as in yoyur code example
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
    systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Color(0xFFE0E0E0),
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    toolbarTextStyle: TextTheme(
            titleMedium: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: 0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
        .bodyMedium,
    titleTextStyle: TextTheme(
            titleLarge: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: 0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
        .titleLarge);
```

---

Additionally, in Android Studio, if you click on Bulb icon, it will show a context to automatically fix this:

[image]

---

**How do I find the correct code?**

Simply <kbd>Ctrl (or Command)</kbd>  + click on the field that's deprecated and read the documentation:

[image]