# The named parameter 'textTheme' isn't defined

Tags: flutter

```
Theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            titleLarge: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The error I am getting is that the parameter `textTheme` is not defined and the quick fix to it is to change it to IconTheme which invalidates the entire code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["'textTheme' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.": No named parameter with the name 'textTheme'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76855423/texttheme-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used-no-named-parameter-with-the)

Comment: Kindly, use the search feature before posting duplicate questions :)